# IOS13 Audio Issue when App sends to background and back to foreground

Tags: swift, scenekit, avaudioplayer

In iOS 13, when i have sent my SceneKit app to the background and bring back to foreground, i have an issue to play audio.

Following code works well to play AudioSource before sending the app to the background.

```
var hitSound: SCNAudioSource!
hitSound = SCNAudioSource(named: "hitSound.mp3")!
hitSound = false
rootNode.runAction(SCNAction.playAudio(hitSound, waitForCompletion: false))
```

When i have sent the app to the background, following warning happened in the console below.

```
[avae]     AVAEInternal.h:109   [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1544:Start: (err = PerformCommand(*ioNode, kAUStartIO, NULL, 0)): error 561015905
```

Moreover, when app brings back to the foreground, following warning happens and stops playing SCNAudioSource sounds. In iOS 12, there is not occurring such a problem.

```
[avae]     AVAEInternal.h:76    required condition is false: [AVAudioPlayerNode.mm:712:ScheduleBuffer: (_outputFormat.channelCount == buffer.format.channelCount)]
```

Comment: What is your AVAudioSession doing about category, activation, and interruptions?

Comment: AVSounds going on playing sound. This is only happens on scnaudiosources.

Comment: OK so you're not willing to answer questions? That makes it hard to help.

Comment: I mean that i am using AVAudioPlayer to play menu sounds and using scnAudioSource to play game sound effects. I do not have an issue of sounds played by AVAudioPlayer in the menu, but game sounds are completely become silent and every collision in the game, i have received an 'AVAEInternal.h:76'  error. I have not defined AVAudioSession

Comment: "I have not defined AVAudioSession" Well, there you go, that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After i have enabled Audio in Background Modes under Signing & Capabilities and added following code into the AppDelegate under didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, problem has been solved.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    // Get the singleton instance.
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        // Set the audio session category, mode, and options.
        try audioSession.setCategory(.playback, mode: .moviePlayback, options: [])
    } catch {
        print("Failed to set audio session category.")
    } 
    return true
}
```

Comment: Didn't need to enable Audio in Background modes, but the above code worked. Thanks.